# timer.tick killing my .net page

Tags: asp.net, timer

I have a simple timer method in vb, that currently does nothing, it just ticks. Once it does however, all my other code on the page stops working.

as an example, I have image buttons on my page that add controls to a static place holder.

```
btnCreate.Text = "Create"
btnCreate.ID = "btnCreateSpecialNotes"
AddHandler btnCreate.Click, AddressOf btnCreateSpecialNotes_Click
plhCreateSpecialNotes.Controls.Add(btnCreate)
```

so without the timer.tick method, that (along with other code not included) would fire off as expected and do what I want, but when the timer.tick happens, everything sort of freezes and nothing works.

My timer is set up as follows

```
<asp:Timer ID="specialNotesTimer" runat="server" Interval="2000" ontick="specialNotesTimer_Tick"></asp: Timer>
```

and in the code behind...

```
Protected Sub specialNotesTimer_Tick(Byval sender as object, Byval e as eventArgs) Handles specialNotesTimer.Tick
'Do things to the page
End Sub
```

Comment: Is all that inside an UpdatePanel and the javascript stop working after the first update ?

Comment: The timer itself is not in an update panel, but the buttons are there after pressing the image button.

Comment: The part is not working is javascript that is not initialize again after the post back ?

Comment: There is no javascript, however the code behind stuff isn't initilizing after the post back.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the main problem I had here was the flow of my html wasn't ending. I restarted my page from scratch slowly, and though I used virtually the identical code, I just triple checked all my close tags and what not in html, and that seemed to solve the problem itself.

I'm sorry there isn't a more in depth answer, but I still don't understand why my old code here wasn't working, but re-doing my page from square one worked for me.

Comment: Posting nothing is better than posting "It magically fixed itself." and then accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

DISCLAIMER: I have never used the System.Web.UI.Timer class.

I think there might be some confusion between client side javascript code and server side C# code.

After reading MSDN, it seems that the Timer control would initiate a full postback every 2000 milliseconds (2 seconds because you say so above). This can only be done in javascript and there needs to be a server side event handler that will perform some task on the server (you call it specialNotesTimer_Tick).

Now, if this task takes longer than 2 seconds to execute, I would assume that you will never see any information on the web page because it would constantly be postbacking (posting back?) and refreshing the screen.

Suggestions:

1. Reconsider your approach for using a timer
2. Increase the timer interval
3. Add an UpdatePanel so the processing happens asynchronously, thus avoiding the screen refresh

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is nothing about C# or javascript in my question.

Comment: Please replace C# with VB.NET in my answer. The concept is still the same, irregardless (yes, I had to use it) of whether it is C# or VB.NET. As for javascript, your ASP:Timer has to produce client side javascript for it to work, otherwise it is just not possible to do the timer magic in plain HTML or CSS.